# Sql query date range issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi i am looking for a query that can give me notification for sale orders i made after 30 days from order date and show the notification for 4 days and disappear after that

for example if i have made sale order on `2016-01-19` after adding 30 days my start date will be `2016-02-18` and adding 4 days to current date my end date will be `2016-02-23`'

i have tried to do that using the below query but it dose not give the desired out put which is records between `2016-02-18` and `2016-02-23`

output i get from below query is empty

```
select * from [dbo].[Orders] where [OrderDate] between Dateadd(d, 30, OrderDate) and Dateadd(d, 4, GETDATE())
```

Comment: _but it dose not give the desired out put_ --> What does that mean? What did you expect and what did you get instead. Please add some sample data.

Comment: i suppose to get records between 2016-01-19 and 2016-02-23 but the output i get is empty

Comment: I'm not following your logic - find me rows where X is between X+30 and (some even greater value). How is that ever meant to work? You're obviously thinking of two separate `OrderDate` values here but I'm not sure where they come from.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever can u help with correct logic then i just need reminder to show  me records i made after 30 days from creation date and disappear after x numbers of days

Comment: Sorry but this does not seem to work `[OrderDate] between Dateadd(d, 30, OrderDate)` I'm afrade a value cannot be greater itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* that you're trying to find orders that occurred between 30 and 34 days ago:

```
select * from [dbo].[Orders]
where [OrderDate] between Dateadd(day, -34, GETDATE()) and
                          Dateadd(day, -30, GETDATE())
```

You *may* wish to adjust these values somewhat, especially if your `OrderDate` values include times also, and because `GETDATE()` values always include time.